# ValidationMessage - Handle multiple errors for the same property

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using ValidationMessage control in MVC. When validating each property, it may have more than one error message to show, but the ValidationMessage only displays the first error message in the list.

Here is an example:

```
ModelState["Key"] = new ModelState();
ModelState["Key"].Errors.Add("Error 1");
ModelState["Key"].Errors.Add("Error 2");
```

and in the html I have: `<%= Html.ValidationMessage("Key")%>`

which displays: `"Error 1"`

I want to see all error messages on the page which will be `"Error 1 Error 2"`

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same problem, so I created an extension method for HtmlHelper as replacement for the MVC ValidationMessage method.

The benefit of this over ValidationSummary method is that it displays error message per field so you can place it right next to each field (same as ValidationMessage method).

```
public static string AllValidationMessage(this HtmlHelper helper, string modelName)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    TagBuilder ulTag = new TagBuilder("ul");
    ulTag.AddCssClass("u-error-list");

    builder.Append(ulTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
    if (helper.ViewData.ModelState.ContainsKey(modelName) &&
        helper.ViewData.ModelState[modelName].Errors.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var err in helper.ViewData.ModelState[modelName].Errors)
        {
            TagBuilder liTag = new TagBuilder("li") { InnerHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(err.ErrorMessage) };
            liTag.AddCssClass("u-error-item");
            builder.Append(liTag.ToString());
        }
    }
    builder.Append(ulTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));

    var msgSpan = helper.ValidationMessage(modelName, "{placeholder}");

    if (msgSpan == null)
        return string.Empty;

    return msgSpan.ToHtmlString().Replace("{placeholder}", builder.ToString());
}

public static string AllValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    return HtmlHelperExtensions.AllValidationMessage(helper, ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));
}
```

**Edit**: added AllValidationMessageFor method
**Edit**: added a null check on msgSpan

Answer (score 2):

With just out-of-the-box MVC, you'll have to add a ValidationSummary:

```
<%= Html.ValidationSummary() %>
```

That will show all ModelErrors.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the solutions presented here and in [How to display multiple validation errors with @Html.ValidationMessageFor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8223197/37760), I created my own multiline validation message for a property.  It behaves somewhat like ValidationSummary but can be used per field.  I use it present a validation message for a collection field of a model.  This allows me to present a summary message for the collection and only the collection.

```
public static MvcHtmlString MultilineValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    var propertyName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    var modelState = htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState;

    // If we have multiple (server-side) validation errors, collect and present them.
    if (modelState.ContainsKey(propertyName) && modelState[propertyName].Errors.Count > 1)
    {
        var msgs = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (ModelError error in modelState[propertyName].Errors)
        {
            msgs.AppendLine(error.ErrorMessage + "<br />");
        }

        // Return standard ValidationMessageFor, overriding the message with our concatenated list of messages.
        var msgSpan = htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(expression, "{0}", htmlAttributes as IDictionary<string, object> ?? htmlAttributes);
        var msgDiv = msgSpan.ToHtmlString().Replace("span", "div");

        return new MvcHtmlString(string.Format(msgDiv, msgs.ToString()));
    }

    // Revert to default behaviour.
    return htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(expression, null, htmlAttributes as IDictionary<string, object> ?? htmlAttributes);
}
```

Comment: is this safe `.Replace("span", "div")`?

Answer (score 1):

As `ModelState` follows a dictionary pattern for errors, it seems ultimately we need to concatenate all the errors into the single `ModelState` key:

```
   ModelState["Key"].Errors.Add("Error 1. " + "Error 2");
```

If you use the [`IValidatableObject`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3400542) [convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.aspx) to perform custom validations, you can convert the validation result failures to `ModelState` entries as follows:

```
var resultsGroupedByMembers = validationResults
    .SelectMany(_ => _.MemberNames.Select(
         x => new {MemberName = x ?? "", 
                   Error = _.ErrorMessage}))
    .GroupBy(_ => _.MemberName);

foreach (var member in resultsGroupedByMembers)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError(
        member.Key,
        string.Join(". ", member.Select(_ => _.Error)));
}
```

The cross join is needed noting there may be more than one `MemberName` per Validation Result. Unbound results are bound to "" and should be available to the `ValidationSummary`.

Answer (score 1):

A more straight to the point approach:

#### Controller:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("other", "error 1");
ModelState.AddModelError("other", "error 2");
ModelState.AddModelError("other", "error 3");
```

#### View:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var error in Html.ViewData.ModelState["other"].Errors)
    {
        <li>@error.ErrorMessage</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also in your Controller Action you can check the

ModelState.IsValid

and if its false, just return the View and the ValidationSumary will be populated.