# How to display multiple validation errors with @Html.ValidationMessageFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I can see that my `ModelState.Values[x].Errors` is correctly populated with the two validation errors for a single property.

If I use a `@Html.ValidationSummary()` in my view, it correctly displays both errors.... albeit at the top of the page, and not next to the offending input.

Using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyProperty)` displays the **first error only** for that property!

How do I show both errors, next to the appropriate input?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One solution is to implement your own extension method on HtmlHelper that does something different to the default ValidationMessageFor behavior.  The sample @Html.ValidationMessagesFor method below will concatenate multiple error messages that have been added to the ModelState during *server-side* validation (only).

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationMessagesFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    var propertyName = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData).PropertyName;
    var modelState = htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState;

    // If we have multiple (server-side) validation errors, collect and present them.
    if (modelState.ContainsKey(propertyName) && modelState[propertyName].Errors.Count > 1)
    {
        var msgs = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (ModelError error in modelState[propertyName].Errors)
        {
            msgs.AppendLine(error.ErrorMessage);
        }

        // Return standard ValidationMessageFor, overriding the message with our concatenated list of messages.
        return htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(expression, msgs.ToString(), htmlAttributes as IDictionary<string, object> ?? htmlAttributes);
    }

    // Revert to default behaviour.
    return htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(expression, null, htmlAttributes as IDictionary<string, object> ?? htmlAttributes);
}
```

This is useful if you have custom business validation you're applying across a collection belonging to your model (for example, cross-checking totals), or checking the model as a whole.

An example using this, where a collection of Order.LineItems are validated server-side:

```
@using MyHtmlHelperExtensions    // namespace containing ValidationMessagesFor
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LineItems)
    <ul>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.LineItems)
    </ul>
    @Html.ValidationMessagesFor(m => m.LineItems)
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Does this work with nested views with viewmodels?
I had to add the following:
`var relativePropertyName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);`
`var propertyName = String.Format("{0}{2}{1}", htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix, relativePropertyName, (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(relativePropertyName) ? String.Empty : "."));`

Comment: Simpler way to get it to work with nested views is:
propertyName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(propertyName)

Comment: Excellent answer, and it works. Except that both my errors are on the same line. I need each error message to be on it's own line. With a <br> tag in between for instance

Comment: @theB3RV or you can use the `white-space: pre-wrap;` css.

Answer (score 5):

The answer Dave A-W provided is essentially correct but will not work in all instances. To get the correct property name the source code of MVC 3 uses:

```
var propertyName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
```

This takes care of any prefixes in the form data